# How to categories different strings as a group using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

## table: Invoice

```
InvoiceID   Status
=========   =======
1           Incompleted
1           Incompleted
2           Completed
2           Incompleted
3           Completed
3           Completed
4           Incompleted
4           Incompleted
4           Completed
```

## my expected result:

```
InvoiceID   Status
=========   ======
1           Incompleted
2           Incompleted
3           Completed
4           Incompleted
```

The logic of grouping is, 
If **Incompleted** exists in the column "Status" while grouping the ID and Status, 
then return “Incompleted"; 
If only the **Completed** exists in the column "Status" while grouping,
then return "Completed";

## SQL:

```
SELECT InvoiceID, Status
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY InvoiceID, Status
```

(This sql output the result which is not I expected. And I do not how to implement the logic to the Status column)
 Anyone has the idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT InvoiceID, MAX(Status)
FROM Invoice
GROUP BY InvoiceID
```

Sql Server should consider Incompleted to be larger than Completed.  If there are any Incompleted in teh InvoiceID, that will be returned, else Completed.  If you have a weird coalation and MAX returns Completed then just use min.

Comment: +1 for clever, but i'm not sure this is very maintainable, nor easy to understand immediately.

Comment: echo the +1 for Clever, but unsure on maintainable. Not sure if it'll work as written here, but case clauses can translate a bit : case when max(case when status = 'complete' then 1 when status = 'incomplete' then 2 end) = 2 then incomplete else complete end.

Comment: @Twelfth Why wouldn't it be maintainable?  It should work as written, I tested it locally.

Comment: I could see maintenance problems if the end user decided that he didnt want to use the word 'Incomplete' as a status, perhaps he uses 'Complete' and 'Partial' or some such.

Comment: @paqogomez While that is true that would also require the user to change the case statement.

Comment: Exactly, but it would be immediately apparent what the problem was in the case statement.  With a `MAX` you dont have that.

Comment: @Vulcronos - Oh yes, it works as is...the maintainable comes more from in 2 years in the future when this person no longer works for the company, is there any point in that code that shows it's expecting incomplete to be alphabetically infront of complete? Could you forward it and have them understand what it is doing? What if 'absent' that comes before complete was added? Comments could probably be left to the same effect. Like I said, very clever and nothing wrong with the solution, I've just spent enough time supporting 'legacy' code to have this solution ring a few alarms for future use

Comment: @Twelfth I like your answer too because it is more flexible for the future plan. And the MAX(CASE WHEN ...) can be used if there are more than 2 status, such as 'Low', 'Medium', 'High'. But I can mark your comment as answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the inner query get only the status which is 'Incompleted'. Link the top query for
   matching ids which will fetch all the 'Incompleted'.
2. In the inner query get only the status which is 'Incompleted'. Link the top query for
   non-matching ids which will fetch all the 'Completed'.
3. Get the union

```
SELECT distinct st1.InvoiceID, 'Incompleted' as Status FROM StatusTest st1  
where InvoiceID in  
(select distinct InvoiceID from StatusTest st2 where status = 'Incompleted')  
UNION  
SELECT distinct st1.InvoiceID, 'Completed'  as Status FROM StatusTest st1  
where InvoiceID not in  
(select distinct InvoiceID from StatusTest st2 where status = 'Incompleted')  
order by InvoiceID
```